# how can we check if a column exists on Table in MySQL without using Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

how we can check if a column exists on Table in MySQL without using Stored Procedure. MySQL v3.23 which won't support writing Store Procedure.

Comment: Can you upgrade? Do you have a manual or a link to one for this antiquated version?

Comment: You can do a lot of things you want if you upgrade. *Highly Advised*.

Answer (score 2):

v3.23 ?? If You know the table name and column name then try describe tablename or show create tablename if you know only column name select * from information schema.columns where column_name = columnname. Show tables should show all tables then manually select column name from the listed tables.

But this version is so ancient I have no idea if any of these will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this, counting the columns in your table using the `information_schema.COLUMNS`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE table_schema = 'your_database_name' 
AND table_name='your_table_name' 
AND column_name='your_column_name';
```

> The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Tabletable provides information about columns in tables.

[Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html)

Comment: Tried this but got this error "Table 'information_schema.columns' doesn't exist"

Comment: Oww. That's sad. You may want to upgrade to version 5.7 or mysql 8.0, can you?

Comment: I put that will be the last option. it takes a bit more effort to upgrade to all systems which we have. so wanted to try if is it possible to do it in an existing one.